# Question regarding $\mathcal{L}\{t*\mathcal{U}(t-2)\}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm working on a problem for homework (* is multiplication not convolution):
$\mathcal{L}\{t*\mathcal{U}(t-2)\}$

I understand that $\mathcal{L}\{(t-a)\mathcal{U}(t-a)\}=e^{-as}F(s)$

The first step of the solution shows that this becomes: $e^{-2s}*\mathcal{L}\{t+2\}$

Why do we take the Laplace transform of $t+2$ instead of just $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $t=(t-2)+2$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\{tu(t-2)\}&=\mathscr{L}\{(t-2+2)u(t-2)\}\\
&=\mathscr{L}\{(t-2)u(t-2)\}+2\mathscr{L}\{u(t-2)\}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Wow, I feel silly.  Thanks.  I hadn't even considered that t = t - 2 + 2.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  So, the first term is $e^{-2s}\mathscr{L}\{t\}$ while the second is $e^{-2s}\mathscr{L}\{2\}$.  So, combine them and you have it!